# Autoadjust view to fill spacing if button or label sets to hide

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, constraints, toolbar

[image: toolBar]

I am using this toold bar with different buttons of different sizes and i am in a condition taht i ahve to hide some buttons according to the backend need and adjust view with the remaining buttons so that it will not look odd. Maximum of i have to hide 3 buttons.

I am not able to find the good approach to do that. 
-I tried to use constrains but the procedure is to complex related to priority.

-Tried to use stack view but it support only IOS9+ versions.

-Tried OAStackView but it did'nt give desired results.

-Even tried to solve the issue by toolBar but not resolved.

Kindly suggest some code or approach.

[image]

Comment: there's an lib that support stackview with iOS 7 and 8, hope it help, [TZStackView](https://github.com/tomvanzummeren/TZStackView)

Comment: i checked the TZStackView and i guess it will help...but the code and library was in SWIFT kindly give an alternate in OBJECTIVE C

Comment: Well theres some way u can do it with storyboard, use `Toolbar` and add a `Flexible Space Bar Button` between each button, it will automatically scale your button to fit the bar if u set any button width = 0, have u tried that solution too? U also don't have to add any constraint to button except the width

Comment: seems like set the `.tittle = @"";` have to go along with `.width = 0;` also

Comment: thanks alot it solved the issue....actually i didnt tried for width=0; what i am doing is set button hidden and removing from subview. But by doing this it didnt refreshes the view...

Comment: Glad it help, what do u mean by refreshes the view?

Comment: means that when i added 5 button on tool bar in XIB and hide one of the button after checking condition then only button hides from that place. the flexible spacing didn't work at that time to fill the empty space. So i guess view is not refreshed to do the changes.

Comment: i think that flexible space bar button wont work so good if u actually remove the button >_< i use the set tittle and set width it work instantly after i did